# Is there a function integrable over the interior of a set but not over the entire set?

Tags: integration

Is there a function Riemann-integrable over the interior of a set but not over the entire set?

Comment: You need the set you integrate over to have Jordan measure to use the Riemann integral (basically so you can get your rectangles in for the upper and lower sums, which will exclude dodgy examples like integrating the indicator function of the rationals over the set of irrationals or similar.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Riemann integrability of a function $f$ over a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ requires $A$ to be Peano-Jordan measurable. This means that the interior $A^\circ$ and the closure $\overline{A}$ must differ by a null set.

Therefore, all measure-theoretic properties of $A$, $A^\circ$ and $\overline{A}$ must be the same, and in particular, they have the same integrable functions.

Comment: I know that there's a theorem which states that if $f$ is integrable over $S$ then it's also integrable over int $S$ (int means interior); my book asked me to show that the converse isn't always true

Comment: @user231951: There must be a notational problem here. Which book are you reading, and what exercise is this? (You'd better put this information in the OP, IMHO)